# Turning a list of strings into function calls

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a list of strings of the form:

```
['function1', 'function2']
```

I'd like to execute them as methods:

```
function1(myVar)
function2(myVar)
```

programatically.

What's the 'right' way?

Comment: Must you use list of strings? Could you use a list of functions instead `[function1, function2]`?

Comment: This seems unbelievably unsafe. I'd recommend using functions in the list.

Comment: The 'right' way is probably not to start with a list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those functions you wanted to invoke are in a module you can access them via `getattr`

```
import your_module

method_names = ['function1', 'function2']

for name in method_names:
  func = gettattr(your_module, name)
  # invoke now
  func() # Pass in your arguments if needed.
```

Comment: Referring to a function by its name is quite common where one wants to refer to a method of any object which does not yet exist, or a (bound) method of multiple similar objects. `getattr(object,name)()` is quite commonly seen, with or without prior sanity checking of whether `name` refers to a "safe" method for this form of invovation. A module is of course an object.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to use function names (strings), your safest bet is to keep a mapping of allowed function names to functions, ie:

```
allowed_functions = {
   "function1": function1,
   "function2": function2,
   # etc
   }
```

then lookup that mapping:

```
def applyfunc(funcname, *args, **kw):
    func = allowed_func.get(funcname, None)
    if func is None:
        raise ValueError("func '%s' is not allowed" % funcname)
    return func(*args, **kw)
```

This is quite similar to Nils Werner's solution using `locals()` but *way* safer (and much easier to maintain to).

Else, remember that python functions are objects (as you noticed from the above example) so if all you want is a list of functions, then it's as simple as it can get:

```
funcs = [function1, function2)
for func in funcs:
    print func(myvar)
```

Comment: I would use a special prefix for allowed functions. I mean for input `f1` the function to be called would be `myfunc_f1`. Equally secure and no lookup table necessary.

Comment: @VPfB the lookup table makes quite clear which functions are allowed to be called that way. From experience it makes maintainance _much_ easier.

Answer (score 2):

`locals()` returns a `dict` of all local variables in this context, your functions should be among them.

```
for name in list:
    locals()[name](myVar)
```

Comment: This is hard to maintains and can be a very serious security issue if the list of function comes from untrusted input...

Comment: Absolutely. I do not recommend doing that, but still it is the answer OP was looking for

Comment: it's not "_the answer" but "one of the possible answers" - cf my own answer for a safer solution.